# Silverlight startup parameters pass to viewmodel

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

im passing my webservice url to my silverlight application via the parameters.

when my application launches it creates the viewmodel for the mainpage before it application_startup event is fired.

in my viewmodel constructor i have  a call to my serviceagent to load some data from the webservice, but the webservice url is not initialised yet due the the viewmodel being constructed before the application_startup event is raised. whats the best way to get around this. Its a friday evening and my brain seems to be pretty fried trying to think of a good solution.

An instance of the ViewModelLocator is created in the app.xaml

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
```

Then in the ViewModelLocator constructor there is a call to create the main page

```
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        CreateMain();
    }

    public static void CreateMain()
    {
        if (_main == null) _main = new MainViewModel();
    }
```

and in my MainViewModel i make a call to my serviceagent

```
    public MainViewModel() : this(new MyServiceAgent()) { }

    public MainViewModel(IMyServiceAgent myServiceAgent)
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {

        }
        else
        {

            ServiceAgent = myServiceAgent;         
            ServiceAgent.GetData();

            RegisterMessageListeners();
            WireUpCommands();
        }
    }
```

App.xaml.cs

```
    public App()
    {
        Startup += Application_Startup;
        Exit += Application_Exit;
        UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.InitParams != null && e.InitParams.Count > 0)
            ParseInitParams(e.InitParams);

        RootVisual = new MainPage();
        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
    }
```

Cheeers

Comment: Why can't you just move the code of where the viewmodellocator is initialized to application_startup? Normally with mvvmlight this is called on application_startup: DispatcherHelper.Initialize(); Also how the viewmodel locator works is that once the viewmodel property is called the first time and there isn't an existing one it will create it, and this will only be called when your window is initialized

Comment: Are you saying that you the constructor for the ViewModel is called before Application.Startup? I've been trying to reproduce this scenario and my Startup is always called before the ViewModel initialization (after all, inside the the Startup handler you create the instance of the view you are going to show) Could you give more details about your setup/scenario?

Comment: its pretty much straight out of the box mvvm light toolkit.. i've attached code above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix my issue i had to remove the line of code from the viewmodellocator constructor that was initialising the MainViewModel

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    //CreateMain();
}
```